# StringGrid - pegar strings com separadores e transformar em células separadas

Tags: delphi-7

saudações a todos

Minha stringGrid já tem mais dados vinda de outros locais (essa imagem é apenas ilustrativa) eu precisaria jogar mais estas informações vinda de uma variável em numa única linha pré determinada preenchendo estas células do stringgrid

essas string é de tamanho desconhecido por exemplo vindo do Edit ou uma variável onde cada elemento's que estiver separada pelo separador       ;       seja exibida em sequência  em células separadas no stringrid em uma única linha

variável :=   t;e;xxxx;t;ooo

nas células do StringGrid ficaria asssim

[ t ] [ e ] [ xxx ] [ t ] [ ooo ] ´

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeçido a quem poder me dar um auxílio

Comment: Podes usar um TStringList, carregar o conteúdo e usar o ExtractStrings para delimitar o dados da sua variável com ";" e depois percorrer a stringlist jogando a informação no stringgrid.

Comment: tudo bem Jefferson Rudolf, obrigado pela dica

poderia me dar um exemplo, usando a TStringList,?

Answer (score -1):

Montei a rotina para ver se ajuda.

```
var
  oSLDados : TStringList;
  sTexto   : String;
  iCont    : Integer;
begin
  sTexto   := 't;e;xxxx;t;ooo';
  oSLDados := TStringList.Create;
  try
    oSLDados.Delimiter       := ';';
    oSLDados.StrictDelimiter := True;
    oSLDados.DelimitedText   := sTexto;

    for iCont := 0 to oSLDados.Count-1 do
      StringGrid1.Cells[iCont,0] := oSLDados.Strings[iCont];
  finally
    FreeAndNil(oSLDados);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom Dia Jefferson Rudolf

eu tava batendo aqui hoje desde de madrugada, com dicas que você tinha me sugerido do TStringList, e acabei de terminar agora, e vim ver os emails,

vou até deixar o código caso alguém precise

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t: TStringList;
  i:integer;
begin
 t := TStringList.create; // cria uma classe
 t.text := stringReplace(Edit1.Text, '|', #13,[rfReplaceAll]);//substitui | por quebra de linha
  for i := 0 to Pred(t.Count) do
      StringGrid1.cells[i+1,2]:=t[i]; // joga todos elementos do edit na stringgrid i+1 para prencher a partir da coluna 2
  t.free; //  destruir a classe
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.Rows[2].Clear;   //  Limpar a linha
end;

Agradeçido mesmo por sua  ajuda

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]